# Git ignore, how to?

Tags: git, ignore

So, I have the next problem.
For example my gitignore file contains this:

`/app/config
/app/tmp
/plugins
/vendors`

If this is my first push to bared remote git server after that described files won't be sended.
But if I at least one time sended this files without gitignore, then made gitignore contains:

`/app/config
/app/tmp
/plugins
/vendors`

Git will push this files too. So, how can I gitignore already pushed files for the next commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove them from history without breaking everything for people which have already cloned your repository, and that is hard and time-consuming anyway. Just remove them with `git rm <...>` and push your changeset.